# Need to check if a product has a tier price

Tags: grouped-products, tierprice, price

I have a problem i cant figure out (mainly because of my lack of experience) When i search for an product which is a grouped product it shows the lowest price which is what i need. However some of these product have tiered prices as well (buy 5 for £3) so i want the tiered price to be displayed on the search and product list pages. I have found the code which displays the lowest price, but i dont know how to check if the product has a tiered price and if so to diplay that price instead of the lowest. I assume you would need an IF statement to check where there is a tiered price on any of the products and if true then display it but i do not know how to code this.

This is the code which is being using to display the lowest price:

```
<?php else: /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>

    <?php
    $showMinPrice = $this->getDisplayMinimalPrice();
    if ($showMinPrice && $_minimalPriceValue) {
        $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue);
        $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, true);
        $price = $showMinPrice ? $_minimalPriceValue : 0;
    } else {
        $price = $_convertedFinalPrice;
        $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $price);
        $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $price, true);
    }
    ?>
    <?php if ($price): ?>
        <div class="price-box">
            <p<?php if ($showMinPrice): ?> class="minimal-price"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php if ($showMinPrice): ?>
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as') ?></span>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. VAT') ?></span>
                        <span class="price"
                              id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_exclTax, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                 <!--   <span class="price-including-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php// echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. VAT') ?></span>
                        <span class="price"
                              id="price-including-tax-<?php //echo $_id ?><?php //echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php //echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_inclTax, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>-->
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php
                    $_showPrice = $_inclTax;
                    if (!$_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax()) {
                        $_showPrice = $_exclTax;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_showPrice, false) ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; /* if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPrice): */ ?>
<?php endif; /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>
```

I assume the If statement would off like this:

```
if ( $_product->getTierPrice()): ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

My main issue is I am not sure what to put inside the statement or where to put it.

If anyone could help that would be great. Also if i have not been to clear or you need more information just let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the tier price of any product, you can use the following code in the conditions :

```
<?php
$tierprices = array();
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'){
    $associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($associatedProducts as $assoc_product) {
    //$assoc_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($assoc_product->getId());// use this only if necessary
        if($assoc_product->getTierPrice()){
            $product_tier_prices = $this->getTierPrices($assoc_product);
            if(count($product_tier_prices) > 0){
                $product_tier_prices = (object)$product_tier_prices;
                foreach($product_tier_prices as $key=>$value){
                    $value = (object)$value;
                    $tierprices[] = $value->price;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
} ?>
```

In this way you will get tier prices of all the associated products of Group product. You need to use the following condition to display "minimum tier" or "as low as":

```
<?php if(count($tierprices) > 0){ ?>
    <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency(min($tierprices), true, false) ?>
    </span>

<?php } else { ?>
all your rest of normal price will come here.
<?php } ?>
```

Note: The code was not tested.

Comment: Thank you but my main issue was what to put in the statement once it has checked for the tier price and where to put the code.

Comment: sorry, I was after your question title :)

Comment: no problem i will make the question a bit clearer :)

Comment: you will have multiple products assigned to a group, how will you go if more than one product has tier price?

Comment: will need to show the lowest tier price

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: brilliant, i will add the code later on when i get a second and let you know how i get on. Thank you for your time and work though