# Magento 2: Group Products How to set Data Position Column Wise

Tags: magento2.3, grouped-products

I want to add one custom column in group product table for displaying Tier Price, but in that case, The products who don't have tier price than it strucure got broken and it does not display data in correct position. i just want to display "-" or anything where tier price is not available. but in that case column's data shifts one step backward. and last column display blank always.
Any solution for this? Please help!
[image: #]

Comment: Please share your .phtml.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped"
           id="super-product-table"
           data-mage-init='{ "Magento_GroupedProduct/js/product-ids-resolver": {} }'>
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Grouped product items')) ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?></th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts) : ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)) : ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)) : ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <?php if (Check Price Tier OR Not) { ?>
                            // Print Your Price
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        &nbsp;
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
                               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getQty() * 1) ?>"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                    </div>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
                <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))) : ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php else : ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) : ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No options of this product are available.')) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```

FOR check tier price [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30164/82670)

Comment: thank you !!  i tried this but still it wont leave the space of the blank column. so i used "colspan" and pass dynamic value.

Comment: @Fenashah Most Wel Come. You can edit this answer and add your solution here so it's helps other people who faced this type of problem.